# Android java.lang.NullPointerException inside try/catch

Tags: java, android, exception

I have the code below (app live, and I got a crash reported at the line with mService.consumePurchase):

```
Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
          try
          {
                int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), sku.mToken);
                if (response == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("onActivityResult consume ok");
                    purchasesOK.add(sku.mSku);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("onActivityResult consume failed");
                    purchasesFail.add(sku.mSku);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                         public void run() 
                         {
                            alert("Store Problems!", "There were problems consuming the product, please use RESTORE button.");
                         }
                    });
                }
          } catch (RemoteException e) {
              purchasesFail.add(sku.mSku);
                System.out.println("onActivityResult consume crashed");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                     public void run() 
                     {
                     alert("Store Problems!", "There were problems consuming the product, please use RESTORE button.");
                     }
                });
            }
     }
});
trd.start();
```

here is the crash report:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.XXXXX.GGActivity.j_ItemPurchase(GGActivity.java:1309) at
>   com.XXXXX.GGLib.step(Native Method) at
>   com.XXXXX.GGView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(GGView.java:436) at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
>   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)

I thought that try/catch will show the popup error in any case of exception. Any ideas what might caused it ? Or how can I avoid it?

Thanks,
/C.

Comment: You've got a NullPointerException, but you're catching RemoteException...

Comment: Crap :-) copy paste combined with too few sleep

Comment: You're catching the wrong Exception, change your catch to catch a NullPointerException :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
catch(NullPointerException e){
    purchasesFail.add(sku.mSku);
    System.out.println("onActivityResult consume crashed");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            alert("Store Problems!", "There were problems consuming the product, please use RESTORE button.");
        }
    });
}
```

in order to show the popup message

Comment: Argh, they commented while I was writing my answer